# How to convert Future to Stream without calling Future.get?

Tags: java, stream, future

Suppose I have a list of Future objects.`List<Future<List<Data>>> futures`. I want to convert it to one `Stream<Data>`.
Apparently I can do like this:

```
List<Data> list=new ArrayList();
for(Future future:futures){
    list.addAll(future.get());
}
return list.steam();
```

But this method have to wait for all futures to return before it can return the Stream.
I want to make it work like a pipeline, the upper layer extract data from the stream and process it as needed, don't have to wait all futures to finish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```java
List<Future<List<Data>>> futures;
return futures.stream().flatMap(future->future.get().stream());
```

`map()` and `flatMap()` are run only when actually using them.

This way, you won't avoid the `get()` call but it is only called at the moment you are using it.